# DataTable variable not being passed to view

Tags: laravel, datatables

I'm using DataTable Editor for the first time and I'm running into an error: Undefined variable: dataTable. I'm including a view in another view as the datable is part of a page with other data on it.

Here is my view...

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
$(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{csrf_token()}}'
        }
    });

    var editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor({
        ajax: "/progress_monitoring_week",
        table: "#week",
        display: "bootstrap",
        fields: [
            {label: "id:", name: "id"},
            {label: "Monitoring ID:", name: "progress_monitoring_id"},
            {label: "Week Number:", name: "week_number"},
            {label: "Monitoring Date:", name: "progress_monitoring_date"},
            {label: "Test Score:", name: "test_score"},
            {label: "Responding:", name: "responding"},
            {label: "Recommendation:", name: "recommentation_id"},
            {label: "Created:", name: "created_at"},
            {label: "Updated:", name: "updated_at"},
        ]
    });

    $('#week').on('click', 'tbody td:not(:first-child)', function (e) {
        editor.inline(this);
    });

    {{$dataTable->generateScripts()}}
});
</script>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    {{$dataTable->table(['id' => 'week'])}}
</div> <!-- end column -->
</div> <!-- end row -->
```

Here is the controller code...

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\DataTables\ProgressMonitoringWeekDataTable;
use App\DataTables\ProgressMonitoringWeekDataTablesEditor;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProgressMonitoringWeekController extends Controller
{
    public function index(ProgressMonitoringWeekDataTable $dataTable)
    {
        return $dataTable->render('progress_monitoring_week.index');
    }

    public function store(ProgressMonitoringWeekDataTablesEditor $editor)
    {
        return $editor->process(request());
    }
}
```

Here is the model code...

```
<?php

namespace App\DataTables;

use App\ProgressMonitoringWeek;
use Yajra\DataTables\Services\DataTable;

class ProgressMonitoringWeekDataTable extends DataTable
{
    /**
     * Build DataTable class.
     *
     * @param mixed $query Results from query() method.
     * @return \Yajra\DataTables\DataTableAbstract
     */
    public function dataTable($query)
    {
        return datatables($query)
            ->addColumn('action', 'progressmonitoringweek.action');
    }

    /**
     * Get query source of dataTable.
     *
     * @param \App\ProgressMonitoringWeek $model
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    public function query(ProgressMonitoringWeek $model)
    {
        return $model->newQuery()->select('id', 'progress_monitoring_id', 'week_number', 'progress_monitoring_date', 'test_score', 'responding', 'recommentation_id', 'created_at', 'updated_at');
    }

    /**
     * Optional method if you want to use html builder.
     *
     * @return \Yajra\DataTables\Html\Builder
     */
    public function html()
    {
        return $this->builder()
            ->columns($this->getColumns())
            ->minifiedAjax()
            ->addAction(['width' => '80px'])
            ->parameters($this->getBuilderParameters());
    }

    /**
     * Get columns.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getColumns()
    {
        return [
            'id',
            'progress_monitoring_id',
            'week_number',
            'progress_monitoring_date',
            'test_score',
            'responding',
            'recommentation_id',
            'created_at',
            'updated_at',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get filename for export.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function filename()
    {
        return 'ProgressMonitoringWeek_' . date('YmdHis');
    }
}
```

I'm not sure the datable variable is not being passed to the view because it is included inside another view, but that is my first guess and I'm not sure how to fix it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: did you use dataTable before?

Comment: Yes, I’m using DataTables in other parts of the app. This is the first time using DataTables Editor, however.

Comment: Sorry, I may have misunderstood your question. I did not use the variable dataTable before. I get the error when I load the page that includes the above view as a subview.

Comment: i just mean dataTables library. datatables itself doesn't need to call jquery ajax. it does all the work by himself.

Answer (score 0):

In your `include` statement just pass the datatable variable as a second argument. This is so that the subview would access it.

```
@include('subview', $dataTable)
```